# email address validation in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to validate email address entered in a textbox, I want error message to be displayed when the user leave email address field with invalid email address "The email address is NOT valid."

This is what I have under a module:

```
Module Connection
Sub ValidateEmail(Byval mail as String)
Dim email as new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\S+@\S+\.\S+")

If email.IsMatch(mail) Then
Else
MsgBox("The Email is Not Valid",msgBoxStyle.Critical,"Invalid Email")
End If
End Sub

End Module
```

Then I double click on the email textbox and put the following code:

```
If txtemail.text = " " Then
Else
ValidateEmail(txtemail.text)
End If
```

Now the thing is when I run my program, it doesn't allow me to finish entering email address, I enter first letter and it gives me error message "The Email is Not Valid", I want it to allow me to finish entering email address then when I move to the next field it can give me the message if the email is not valid.

Anyone who understand my problem here, please help.

Thank You

Answer (score 4):

When you double click `TextBox` it creates `TextBox_TextChanged` eventhandler, which is fired every time the text changes inside textbox, instead you need to subscribe to the event which is fired when focus is lost on `TextBox`, that is `TextBox_Leave`.
For subscribing to `Leave` event click F4 on `TextBox` and Properties window will open, navigate to `Events` tab, find `Leave` event and double click it.

Comment: Thanks Man it just worked

Comment: Consider making answers as "Accepted" when it really helps

Answer (score 0):

You are using the OnChange event

You could use the Onleave, and in the event of an error set focus back to the text box.
You could skip checking for a valid format until a certain amount is entered in the Onchange, but do the full check onLeave.

Either of the above has knock on effects as presumably some later function needs email to be valid. So you'll need to check again before you try a send, or a save.

Or you could get rid of notification using a message box, say show an error image when it's invalid. The later functionality the depends on a valid pattern, could then simply check to see if the "error component" is visible. More like I'd you'd validate a form on web page.

The last one is my preference, not a big fan of message box errors.